# NancyFX - Custom 404 handler overrides every 404 response

Tags: c#, nancy

I did my custom 404 handler for NancyFX and it works fine but there is a problem. Problem is that it overrides even those requests where I want to send 404 code but with my custom message e.g. "User not found".

## Handler

```
public class NotFoundHandler : IStatusCodeHandler
{
    public bool HandlesStatusCode(HttpStatusCode statusCode, NancyContext context)
    {
        if (statusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            // How to check here if the url actually exists?
            // I don't want every 404 request to be the same
            // I want to send custom 404 with Response.AsJson(object, HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void Handle(HttpStatusCode statusCode, NancyContext context)
    {
        context.Response = new TextResponse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Message = "Resource not found" }, Formatting.Indented))
        {
            StatusCode = statusCode,
            ContentType = "application/json"
        };
    }
}
```

## Problem

```
Get["/"] = _ =>
{
    // This will not show "User not found", instead it will be overriden and it will show "Resource not found"
    return Response.AsJson(new { Message = "User not found" }, HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You decide which responses you want to handle in your `IStatusCodeHandler` implementation(s). Right now you are, only, checking the status code itself, without adding context to it. What you could do (for example) would be to only overwrite `context.Response` if it doesn't contain a Response that meets certain criterion, such as being of the type `JsonResponse`

```
    if(!(context.Response Is JsonResponse))
    {
            context.Response = new TextResponse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Message = "Resource not found" }, Formatting.Indented))
            {
                StatusCode = statusCode,
                ContentType = "application/json"
            };
    }
```

Since you have access to the full `NancyContext`, you also have access to the entire `Request` and `Response` (which was returned by a route or something else in the request pipeline). Further you can stick arbitrary metadata in `NancyContext.Items` if you need even more control.

Hope this helps